# is my .htaccess faulty after change address?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My project (with WAMP) has address like `localhost:8080/MyProject/`.

Now my project is online and has adress like `http://MyProject.mydomain.com/`

All actions and param is like this `localhost:8080/MyProject/action/param`

When I try `http://MyProject.mydomain.com/login`, I have a 404 not found error.

Here my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# NC : no case
# L : Last

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  index.php?action=$1&param=$2 [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Did you enabled the mod_rewrite for the new environment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check to see if the provider hosting your project enables the processing of the .htaccess file?  If it is disabled then you need to see if they allow you to overwrite their defaults.

This information can typically be found in their FAQs/Knowledgebase.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `RewriteBase /` before all `RewriteRule` and it's work!

Thanks guys!